# How to override Backbone collection to return models in child property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an API that returns a collection of models, but it's not in the traditional format that Backbone expects - an array of models.  Instead, there are some global properties to the collection, then the models are in an array assigned to a property of the collection.  Something like this:

```
{
    foo: 'bar',
    models: [
        { id: 1, prop1: 'abc' },
        { id: 2, prop1: 'xyz' },
        { id: 3, prop1: '123' }
    ]
}
```

I can't change the API so I have to live with this data format.  How do I massage the data so that the Backbone collection will get just the array of models?  I've had a similar situation with a model and just wrote a custom toJSON() method which return the correct property with the model data, but that doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override your collection's [`parse` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse), where you get the whole response object and you need return an array what Backbone will use to fill in your collection:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.models;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, no wonder.  I had just assumed that the toJSON() method played that role, as it did with Models.  Thanks.